# How do you assign a pointer to a pointer which is within a struct?

Tags: c

How do you assign a pointer to a pointer which is within a struct?

```
struct student{
    char name[24];
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
}

struct aClass{
    struct student *students;
    int rowsUsed;
}

void addTo(struct aClass *db, struct student *a){
    ...
}
```

how would I assign a pointer to another pointer that is within a struct?

I've tried

```
db -> students[db -> rowsUsed] = *a;
db -> rowsUsed = db -> rowsUsed + 1;
```

but it's not working.

Comment: What you have seems okay, provided that you actually set `db` to point to an object and properly initialized `db->rowsUsed`.  But you didn't show that code so we can't be sure whether you did so.  Please provide a [mcve], and explain what's wrong in more precise terms than "it's not working".

Comment: @NateEldredge sorry, I had to add a wee bit more. In reality I'm actually assigning a pointer to another, but one pointer is within a struct, so I'm not 100% how to do it that way.

Comment: If there are `...`s in your code, it's not a reproducible example.  Can I feed it to a compiler and get the same error you're seeing?

Comment: It's suspicious that the `struct b` is being passed to `addTo` by value.  Any changes made to `all` within `addTo` will only affect its local copy, not whatever object was passed by the caller.

Comment: @NateEldredge cheers, I changed it.

Comment: Don't change your question the whole time, especially after somebody has answered.

Comment: shouldn't it be struct aClass *db?

Comment: @AndersK sorry someone asked for a more descriptive question. Once again sorry.

Comment: In C struct statements ends with `;`.

Comment: Change `db -> students[db -> rowsUsed] = a;` to `db -> students[db -> rowsUsed] = *a;` if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the types...

```
db -> students[db -> rowsUsed] = a;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^
   Type is "struct student"      Type is "pointer to struct student"
```

So you are trying to do an assign between to objects with incompatible types. That will fail. You need the same type on both sides of the operator.

Maybe you want

```
db -> students[db -> rowsUsed] = *a;
                                 ^^
                                 Now it's the struct student that a points to
```